# How do I write subscripted and superscripted below each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create something like this, with two numbers on top of each other (subscript and superscript):

[image: Example]

Is this possible without using any complex script like MathJax?

Comment: of course you can, but requires some html markup i.e. put each word into a span tag, is that OK?

Comment: Doesn't work like in the image. They would just be seperated but not in one "column".

Comment: still don't understand, can you suggest a markup, like <sup>220</sup><sub>86</sub><span>Rn</span> I guess.

Comment: Well, it would help at first, yes. But I'm not satisfied by that result. I want the sub to be directly below the sup

Comment: does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/0o9sdeku/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for a container element around the two, displayed as an inline-table:

```css
.supsubcontainer {
    display:inline-table;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.supsubcontainer sup, .supsubcontainer sub {
    display:table-row;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="supsubcontainer"><sup>220</sup> <sub>86</sub></span> Rn</p>
```

You might want to play around with `line-height`, `font-size` and the `vertical-align` of the inline table to get it to look exactly like you want.

Comment: masterpiece +1, makes me jealous.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/Lnhoynpd/)

```
<sup>220</sup><sub style="margin-left:-15px">86</sub><span style="margin-left:3px;">Rn</span>
```

Advantage : tableless design
Disadvantage : you need to match your left margin depending on the characters(i.e numbers.)

Comment: i thought about it, but i doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/Lnhoynpd/1/ when the number gets larger, mis-aligned.

Comment: That is what he has mentioned as a disadvantage.

Comment: Yep. Your table solution is perfect. I gave my vote for that.